# Qt PushButton Signals and Slots

Tags: qt, show, slot, qpushbutton

I'm pretty much a beginner at Qt. Anyway, I'm trying to use signals and slots to show a widget once the button is pressed. I created the widget, and have the connect() thing all done, but what do I put in the SLOT() thing? I've tried show(widget), but to be honest I have no clue what to put there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QWidget` has a public slot called [show()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#show). You can connect your button's [clicked()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal to your widget's [show()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#show) slot. [Read more about signals and slots here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html).

Example:

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
widget->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), widget, SLOT(show()));
```

You could also create your own slot and call `widget->show()` from there. Then connect the button's `clicked()` signal to your slot.

Example:

```
//myclass.h
...
public:
   QWidget *myWidget;

public slots:
   void mySlot();
```

```
//myclass.cpp
...
   connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(mySlot()));
...

void MyClass::mySlot()
{
   myWidget->show();
}
```